# Text of Labels disappears after UICollectionView reloads

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the Swift 2.3 branch [code](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift/tree/swift-2.3).
I've got a `UICollectionViewCell` where I use `ActiveLabel` inside the cell. Label has callback for **#**, url. So upon url click, I launch a modal View Controller. Upon dismissing the View Controller, the label which had both url & **#** inside the cell renders it and then the text with **#** disappears!

Label in `collectionViewCell`:

```
class CustomViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
lazy var messageLabel : ActiveLabel = {
        let label = ActiveLabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont(name: SWFontNames.regularFont, size: SWFontSize.medium)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineSpacing = 4
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.hashtagColor = UIColor().rgb(90, green: 200, blue: 250)
        label.mentionColor = UIColor(red: 238.0/255, green: 85.0/255, blue: 96.0/255, alpha: 1)
        label.URLColor = UIColor(red: 85.0/255, green: 238.0/255, blue: 151.0/255, alpha: 1)
        label.URLSelectedColor = UIColor(red: 82.0/255, green: 190.0/255, blue: 41.0/255, alpha: 1)
        return label
    }()

override init(frame:CGRect) {
super.init(frame:frame)
// Do auto layout
}

}
```

EDIT1: Cell

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let customcell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomViewCell
 let feedData = profileFeed[indexPath.item]
 customcell.messageLabel.text = feedData.commentContent
 return customCell
}
```

Test Cases:

```
Input String: https://www.youtube.com #dealWith yes > after reload > https://www.youtube.com
Input String: https://www.yahoo.com > https://
Input String: hi #deal #done > remains same, hi #deal #done
```

Comment: Please share your code inside `cellForItemAt:`.

Comment: @Koen shared as requested

Comment: I think you need to recreate your message label for each cell inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, it looks like you are sharing it now between different cells.

Comment: I'm dequeing it, and I'm not sure what you meant by sharing.

Comment: So if you dequeue it, it is possible that the sample instance of the label is used by two different cells and then the contents will conflict. I would try putting the `var messageLabel : ActiveLabel = { ... }` part inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.  Otherwise, it could be a bug in `ActiveLabel`, but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: you use this https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift ?